# Multiple files, multiple plots saved to a multipage, single pdf file

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, pdfpages

I am working with >100 csv files while I am opening and plotting in a loop. My aim is to save each plot on a pdf page and generate a big pdf file with each page containing plot from a single file. I am looking at these examples - [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419001/is-it-possible-to-append-figures-to-matplotlibs-pdfpages) and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783151/how-to-save-multiple-seaborn-plots-into-single-pdf-file). Trying out combinations using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf` I am unable to get the required result.

Here I re-create my code and the approach I am using:

```
pdf = PdfPages('alltogther.pdf')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

for file in glob.glob('path*'):
    df_in=pd.read_csv(file)

    df_d = df_in.resample('d') 
    df_m = df_in.resample('m') 

    y1=df_d['column1']
    y2=df_m['column2'] 
    
    plt.plot(y1,linewidth='2.5') 
    plt.plot(y2,linewidth='2.5')
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

With this all the plots are getting superimposed on the same figure and the pdf generated is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the line

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
```

Inside the loop, otherwise each iteration will use the same figure instance instead of a new instance. Also note that you need to close the pdf when you are done with it. So the code should be

```py
pdf = PdfPages('alltogther.pdf')

for file in glob.glob('path*'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
    df_in=pd.read_csv(file)

    df_d = df_in.resample('d') 
    df_m = df_in.resample('m') 

    y1=df_d['column1']
    y2=df_m['column2'] 

    plt.plot(y1,linewidth='2.5') 
    plt.plot(y2,linewidth='2.5')
    pdf.savefig(fig) 

pdf.close()
```

#### Edit

---

Complete, self-contained example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import numpy as np

pdf = PdfPages('out.pdf')
for i in range(5):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
    plt.plot(np.random.random(10), linestyle=None, marker='.')
    pdf.savefig(fig)

pdf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The pdf is only storing the last graph and not all.

Comment: @Learning_datascience I have added a complete, self-contained example. If you run that **exact** code you should get a pdf with 5 pages each containing a single, different figure. Can you try it and see if you get the result I just described?