# Save multiple seaborn plots into one pdf file

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, save, seaborn

At the moment I'm learning how to work with `matplotlib` and `seaborn` and the concept behind it seems quite strange to me. One would expect the `sns.countplot` function to return an object that has a `.plot()` and `.save()` fuction so one could work with the plot in a different function.
Instead it seems that every call to `sns.countplot` overwrites the previous object (see MWE).

So one the one hand It would be grate if someone could provide a explanation of the `matplotlib` and `seaborn` interface (or have some good doku linked). Since all the doku I read wasn't of any great help.

On the other hand I have a function that returns some plots, which I want to save as an `.pdf` file with one plot per page. I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783151/) but can't copy the code over in a way to make my MWE work.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import seaborn as sns


def generate_plots():

    penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

    countplot_sex = sns.countplot(y='sex', data=penguins)
    countplot_species = sns.countplot(y='species', data=penguins)
    countplot_island = sns.countplot(y='island', data=penguins)

    # As showes
    # print(countplot_sex) -> AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
    # print(countplot_species) -> AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
    # print(countplot_island) -> AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
    # All three variables contain the same object

    return(countplot_sex, countplot_species, countplot_island)


def plots2pdf(plots, fname):  # from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489936
    pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

    for plot in plots:
        pass
        # TODO save plot
        # Does not work: plot.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

    pp.savefig()
    pp.close()


def main():
    plots2pdf(generate_plots(), 'multipage.pdf')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My Idea is to have a somewhat decent software architecture with one function generating plots and another function saving them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by default, `sns.countplot` will do its plotting on the current matplotlib Axes instance. From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html):

> `ax` matplotlib Axes, optional
>
> Axes object to draw the plot onto, otherwise uses the current Axes.

One solution would be to define a small function that creates a new figure and Axes instance, then passes that to `sns.countplot`, to ensure it is plotted on a new figure and does not overwrite the previous one. This is what I have shown in the example below. An alternative would be to just create 3 figures and axes, and then pass each one to the `sns.countplot` function yourself.

Then in your `plots2pdf` function, you can iterate over the Axes, and pass their figure instances to the `PdfPages` instance when you save. (Note: Since you create the figures in the `generate_plots` function, an alternative would be to return the figure instances from that function, then you have them ready to pass into the `pp.savefig` function, but I did it this way so the output from your function remained the same).

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_plots():

    penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

    def my_countplot(y, data):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.countplot(y=y, data=data)
        return ax

    countplot_sex = my_countplot(y='sex', data=penguins)
    countplot_species = my_countplot(y='species', data=penguins)
    countplot_island = my_countplot(y='island', data=penguins)

    return(countplot_sex, countplot_species, countplot_island)


def plots2pdf(plots, fname):

    with PdfPages(fname) as pp:

        for plot in plots:

           pp.savefig(plot.figure)

def main():
    plots2pdf(generate_plots(), 'multipage.pdf')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A screenshot of the multipage pdf produced:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, since beyond the MWE I'm using other `sns` functions too I changed your function into: `def myplot(func): _, axsis = plt.subplots(); func(); return(axsis)` Which I can call via: `myplot(lambda: sns.heatmap(. . .))`